# Signing $y''$ from $\log(\frac{x+y}{x})=x+y$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $x,y>0$ are positive reals such that $y$ is defined implicitly in terms of $x$ via:
>   $$
> \log\left(\frac{x+y}{x}\right)=x+y.\tag{$\star$}
> $$
>   I would like study the sign of $y''$.

**Attempt**: Write ($\star$) as
$$
\log(x+y)-\log(x)=x+y.
$$
Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$ yields
$$
\frac{1+y'}{x+y}-\frac{1}{x}=1+y'\tag{$\star\star$}
$$
which can be solved to get 
$$
1+y'=\frac{x+y}{x(1-x-y)}\cdot
$$
Differentiate both sides of ($\star\star$) w.r.t. $x$ to get
$$
\frac{(x+y)y''-(1+y')^2}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}=y''
$$
which, after feeding to Mathematica while using $1+y'$ found above, gives
$$
y''=\frac{(x+y-2) (x+y)^2}{x^2 (x+y-1)^3}
$$
which can clearly take on positive and negative values depending on $x+y$. Indeed, looking back at ($\star$), we can freely vary $x+y$: to have $x+y=r>0$, simply set
$$
x=e^{-r}r,\quad y=(1-e^{-r})r.
$$
**Is my attempt here reasonable to you?** The reason I'm not confident is that if I feed ($\star$) directly to Mathematica, I get
$$
y=-x-\text{ProductLog}[-x]
$$
where (according to Help File) $\text{ProductLog}[z]$ gives the principal solution for $w$ in $z=we^w$. Then I plotted
$$
\partial_x(\partial_x(-x-\text{ProductLog}[-x]))
$$
and saw something that is only positive:

[image]

**What is going on? Can someone please explain this seeming discrepancy?**

Comment: One thing you can do is define $z(x)=y(x)+x$; then $\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and the calculations are a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $y$ isn't globally uniquely determined, i.e. there are multiple functions $y_i(x)$ that verify $(\star)$. In $\mathbb C$ these are infinite, while in $\mathbb R$ there are two, and you have, via Mathematica, found just one of them. The other solution can be seen [here](http://tinyurl.com/lxt5bgk) to vary in sign  *as you predicted* (to know that this is a solution, see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ln%28%28x%2By%29%2Fx%29+%3D+x%2B+y+for+y). If you want a single function, you'll have to work with a local definition of $y(x)$ in neighbourhoods of concrete solutions $(x_0,y_0)$.

If the global vs. local aspect seems confusing, take the unit circumference as an example: there is no function $y(x)$ that traverses the entire curve of solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 1$, but you can define, for every solution $(x_0,y_0)$, a function $y(x)$ that passes through $(x_0,y_0)$ and such that every $(x,y(x))$ is a solution.

I have to add that I'm not terribly familiar with the Lambert function, so if anyone notices a mistake please correct it.